# "Class does not exist exception" in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4, voyager

When I'm trying to create a bread for the table `p_catogegory` in the Voyager Laravel admin theme, it shows this error:

[image]

How can I fix this? Here is the bread structure for my table:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you have typo here? Shouldn't be `p_category` and not `p_cateogry` and so on in other places?

Answer (score 0):

i placed the wrong code in model that's why its not working properly